# make axes invisible or delete plot completely

Tags: matlab, axes

I have a matlab gui that shall contain 4 plots. The first plot shall be updated if a different file is selected in a list. the other 3 shall only be visible (and be calculated) on request.

However I fail to make plots 2-4 invisible after they have been plotted once.

I tried

```
set(handles.axesImage, 'Visible', 'off');
```

but that only deletes the axis, not the whole plot.

EDIT:
Instead of making things unvisible, is it also possible to actually delele the content? Typically I would call `close(hfig);`, but here i have no figure.

I tried

```
handles2hide = [axisObj;cell2mat(get(axisObj,'Children'))]; 
delete(handles2hide);
```

But that fails for the unplotted axes (after startup)

EDIT:
I changed the code to:

```
axisObj = handles.axesContour;
if ishandle(axisObj)
    handles2delete = get(axisObj,'Children');
    delete(handles2delete);
    set(axisObj,'visible','off') 
end
if (isfield(handles,'contour') && isfield(handles.contour,'hColorbar'))
    delete(handles.contour.hColorbar);
    delete(handles.contour.hColorbarLabel);
end
```

However the colorbar remains undeleted and `handles.contour.hColorbar` fails with `Invalid handle object.`

Comment: Deleting works for me. Maybe you want to check that you only delete valid handles, i.e. `delete(handles2hide(ishandle(handles2hide)))`

Comment: I get an error before that: `??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.` in line `handles2hide = [cell2mat(get(axisObj,'Children'))];`. I had to remove the `axisObj` from the delete list, because I can not plot anymore to a deleted axis...

Comment: I removed `cell2mat` and now the plot is deleted, however the colorbar and color label still remain. And even if I save their handles to deleted them this does not work, because deleting fails because they are not recognised as handles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved it with

```
function z_removePlots(handles)

if (isfield(handles,'image') && isfield(handles.image,'hplot'))
    if ishandle(handles.image.hplot)
        delete(handles.image.hplot);
        delete(findall(gcf,'tag','Colorbar'));
        handles.image.hplot = 0;
        set(handles.axesImage, 'Visible', 'off');
    end
end
if (isfield(handles,'contour') && isfield(handles.contour,'hplot'))
    if ishandle(handles.contour.hplot)
        delete(handles.contour.hplot);
        handles.contour.hplot = 0;
        ClearLinesFromAxes(handles.axesContour)
        set(handles.axesContour, 'Visible', 'off');
    end
end
guidata(handles.output,handles);
```

with

```
function ClearLinesFromAxes(axisObj)
if ishandle(axisObj)
    handles2delete = get(axisObj,'Children');
    delete(handles2delete);
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to hide not only the axes, but all of their children:

```
handles2hide = [handles.axesImage;cell2mat(get(handles.axesImage,'Children'))];
set(handles2hide,'visible','off')
```

The cell2mat is needed only if there are more than one handle stored in `handles.axesImage`

Note that you'll need the full list of handles to make everything visible again.

**EDIT**

If you want to delete all axes (includes colorbars) and their children on a figure, you can do the following (if you have to exclude certain axes, you can use `setdiff` on the lists of handles):

```
ah = findall(yourFigureHandle,'type','axes')
if ~isempty(ah)
   delete(ah)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
    set(allchild(handles.axes1),'visible','off'); 
    set(handles.axes1,'visible','off');
```

for hiding my axes.
I found the solution here:
[Visible axes off](http://www.gomatlab.de/gui-axes-visible-t660.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have use the handles to the subplots and plots:

```
h(1)=subplot(221);
    p(1)=plot(rand(10,1));
h(2)=subplot(222);
    p(2)=plot(rand(10,1));
h(3)=subplot(223);
    p(3)=plot(rand(10,1));
h(4)=subplot(224);
    p(4)=plot(rand(10,1));


set([h(2) p(2)],'visible','off')
```

hides the 2nd plot. @Jonas answer seems more complete however. It's certainly easier, because you don't have to collect the children yourself manually as I did here.

Comment: `h(2)=subplot(222);plot(rand(10)); set(h(2),'visible','off')` is the problem, if I understand the OP correctly

Comment: @Jonas yeah, struck that problem too when extending my tests... update^^

Comment: I added a subplot to my gui in the code: that only messes up the whole gui and makes all axes handles invalid -> without further work (which I do no know) unusable.