# Why is a plot handle always invalid?

Tags: matlab, plot, handle

I want to delete a plot and its colorbar ( actually I want to delete everything in a plot, but that seams to be almost impossible, see [make axes invisible or delete plot completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865541/make-axes-invisible-or-delete-plot-completely))

I do this:

In the plot

```
hplot = pcolor(xAxis, yAxis, Data2D); 
hcb = colorbar;
handles.image.hColorbar = hcb;
handles.image.hplot = hplot;
guidata(handles.output,handles);
```

later in the gui:

```
if (isfield(handles,'image') && isfield(handles.image,'hplot'))
    if (handles.image.hplot~=0)
        delete(handles.image.hplot);
        delete(handles.image.hColorbar);
        handles.image.hplot = 0;
    end
end
```

It works for `delete(handles.image.hplot)` but fails for `handles.image.hColorbar` with invalid handle - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet works fine here...

In general, it is advisable to check for `ishandle()` on both objects, so that you don't have to set `handles.image.hplot = 0`. Since `delete` has made the handle invalid, it will never pass the `ishandle` check until you re-assign a new, valid handle to it.

If the code doesn't pass the `ishandle()` tests, it means it was `deleted` already, so no need to `delete` it again.