# How to remove a children object from a figure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axes

How can I remove a `children` object from a `figure` in MATLAB?

1- Suppose I want to **remove** (not invisible) an `axes` from a `figure`. How to do it?
2- Since `axes` is a children of `figure`, can the same approach be used in removing any type of children of a `figure`?

I searched here, and docs but **I don't want to make it invisible**. I want to delete it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make axes invisible or delete plot completely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865541/make-axes-invisible-or-delete-plot-completely)

Comment: The answer mentioned there makes axes invisible instead of delete

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11865694/3871918

Comment: Ah it seems there WAS a "delete" answer. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the axes handle (from either `figure.Children` or otherwise), you can simply use `delete` to remove it from the figure regardless of it's visibility.

```
fig = figure();
hax = axes('Parent', fig);

% Delete the axes directly
delete(hax)
```

If you don't have access to the handle, you can get it using `findobj` or `findall` (`findall` even locates `axes` with `HandleVisibility` turned to `'off'`) to locate axes which belong to your figure and then `delete` to remove it.

```
delete(findobj(gcf, 'type', 'axes'));
% delete(findall(gcf, 'type', 'axes'));
```

If your axes has a specific `Tag` property, you can further filter by that

```
delete(findobj(gcf, 'type', 'axes', 'tag', 'mytag'));
% delete(findall(gcf, 'type', 'axes', 'tag', 'mytag'));
```

You can pass any property / value pair to `findobj` and `findall` so you could even just delete all invisible axes:

```
delete(findobj(gcf, 'type', 'axes', 'visible', 'off'))
```

Comment: A comprehensive answer. Thanks